# How do I implement solid colours for zone boundaries in Highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

I have set up a line chart in Highcharts with a different colour to indicate values reaching unacceptably high values (95% or above).

To achieve this, I added zones to my series configuration, as follows:

```
zones: [{
    value: 95,
    color: 'lightblue'
}, {
    color: 'red'
}]
```

One blue zone encompasses values up to 95, and another red zone shows higher values.

It seems that when values come close to 95, the line starts to turn red, meaning that on a chart where the line approaches but never hits 95%, the line shows (partially) red.

I would like to prevent this, and only turn the line red if the value hits 95%. Is there a way to do this?

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/o53pmtLo/) is a demo showing the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit tricky question.

First of all, your data looks like a straight line and **very** close to **95**. In these cases, color overlapping with using `zones` property is inevitable.

But there is a trick you can try;

Highcharts has a plug-in called **MultiColor** which you can find [here](http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/33/Multicolor%20series).

With using this plugin, you can create multicolor line charts;

[image]

What we can do for your chart is to modify data to include colors like,

```
data: [94.0, 94.1, 94.2, 94.3, 94.4, 94.5, 94.6, 94.7, 94.8, 94.9, 94.8, 94.7, {y: 95.0, segmentColor: 'red'},{y: 95.4, segmentColor: 'red'}, {y: 96.1, segmentColor: 'red'}]
```

And this modification will give us requested result:

[image]

Live example: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/emrebolat/dzmtr1hu/).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response! A clean way to solve the problem. Much appreciated.